# Why equations are distributed over couple of lines in Latex

Tags: pdftex

I am facing a problem in some of my equations written in latex as it is distributed over two lines and I don't why this happens.
For example, the attached picture shows the script and the output in the pdf files. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: This is the script of defining the function]

[image: This is the output in the pdf file]

Furthermore, after the bracket some words like (u) is not written at all. Why is that.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please never post screenshots of code. Don't make others retype your code. Post a complete minimal document in a code block that can be copied and pasted and run as is. That code has errors. Never ignore errors. What are you trying to accomplish with `\emph` in math mode? Math mode letters are italicized by default. Does `\sigma_i = \upsilon_p \rho (\dot{u}^{ff} - \dot{u}_{i}^{m})` do what you want? If not, post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There should be error messages in your log pointing out the problems.  The main one is that `equation` establishes math mode, and using `$` within display math is incorrect -- it turns off math mode and changes many processing conventions (also causing many additional irrelevant error messages).  Also, `\emph` shouldn't be used within math mode; letters within math are by default italic.

Comment: never ignore error messages, after _any_ error, if you scroll past and make a pdf it is just usable as a debugging aid, tex makes no attempt at making usable output it just tries to recover enough to process the rest of th file, for checking.

Answer (score 1):

Please, consult a beginner's manual for LaTeX. See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/)

You mustn't use `$` inside `equation` and that's the reason for the errors you get: `equation` already uses math mode.

Also, `\emph` is not for math formulas; single letters will be automatically typeset in italics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{NEW}
\sigma_{i} = \upsilon_{p}\rho(\dot{u}^{ff}-\dot{u}_{i}^{m})
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If `ff` is to be a single symbol, you might use `\mathit{ff}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{NEW}
\sigma_{i} = \upsilon_{p}\rho(\dot{u}^{\mathit{ff}}-\dot{u}_{i}^{m})
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Much appreciated.